# I want to the best schema to store reactions

Tags: mysql, database

i want to get different like reactions from user (like,heart,clapping,etc) for a post how i store in database

My Post Table is like below

```
| ID | TITLE | SLUG | CONTENT | COMMENTS_COUNT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best solution is likely to be a separate table, called something like `post_reactions`. That table would contain `user_id`, `post_id`, and `type` columns. This allows the use of things like `COUNT`, `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the data sliced-and-diced up as needed.

Comment: i mean to say what is the schema of reaction table to store reactions